# Ввод текста в андроид симуляторе

Tags: android

Может кто подскажет как в андроид симуляторе вводить текст в поля текстовые с помощью комповой клавы. У меня тока английские буквы вводятся (когда выключил hardware keyboard). Как переключится на русские? Все перепробовал в настройках, глухо.

Comment: Не английскую клавиатуру вы конечно же установили и выбрали в настройках? И да, слегка позанудствую: в поставке Android SDK идёт именно эмулятор, а не симулятор.

Comment: Ставил русскую:
http://savepic.net/3781418.htm
http://savepic.org/3556373.png

Comment: Точно. Это я упустил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это Вы программную настроили - нужно настроить физическую:       http://savepic.org/3542054.png   
Только вот на моём планшете почему-то такой настройки нет...